# Run an executable after moving it to a different directory in the make file

Tags: c++, makefile

In my make file I try to move my executable to a different release directory and then run the program but I am having some issues when I run the program from the make file

```
mv main ../Data/Derived/Release;
./Data/Derived/Release/main
```

I get the `command not found` error.

When I go to the release folder and  run `./main` From the command line,  it works as expected.  I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You moved the program to `../Data/Derived/Release`.

Then you tried to run `./Data/Derived/Release`.

These are not the same path. `..` means "the parent directory", but `.` means "this directory".

Looks like you missed out a dot.